# Как вызвать функцию при клике? js

Tags: javascript, функции, методы, click

> Есть вот такой вот код, который берёт инфу из localStorage и отрисовывает её на другой вкладке. Всё работает нормально до тех пор, пока я не повешу эту функцию на клик. Когда я вышаю на клик и перехожу на ту вкладку, где должна отрисовываться инфа, то мне пишет Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. ticketButton находится во вкладке, где нужно тыкнуть на эту кнопку и и отобразить инфу на на другую вкладку в блок ticketsContainer

```
ticketButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    displayTickets();
})

function displayTickets() {
    let seatsItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('seats'));
    let time = localStorage.getItem('time');
    let day = localStorage.getItem('day');
    let ticketsContainer = document.querySelector('.ticketsContainer');

    if(seatsItems && ticketsContainer) {
        ticketsContainer.innerHTML = '';
        Object.values(seatsItems).map(item => {
            ticketsContainer.innerHTML += `
                <div class="ticket">
                    <div class="ticketImage">
                        <img src="${item.img}" class="ticketImg"/>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="ticketAbout">
                        <div class="ticketInforamtion">
                            <p>Ваш ряд: ${item.row}</p>
                            <p>Ваше место: ${item.seat}</p>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="ticketTime">
                            <p>${day},</p>
                            <p> ${time}</p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="${item.barcode}" class="barcode"/>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            `;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут приходится гадать, что за вкладки (браузера или самописные какие-то), где ticketButton и прочее. Отредактируйте вопрос, иначе ответы будут пальцем в небо пока вам не понравится.

Comment: Всё, вроде бы написал понятно

Comment: Ну вы умалчиваете что за вкладки, почему ticketButton становится null не ясно. Возможно у вас этот код вызывается в каждой вкладке, например повешен на "`tab.onchаnge`" и во второй вкладке просто нет кнопки. В общем не ясно как отвечать, не хватает информации. Вкладок в вашем коде нет, заметьте, а вы про них говорите.

Comment: У меня есть два html файла, в первом находится кнопка, во вторном контейнер, куда должна отрисовываться инфа. И функция работает как следует до тех пор, пока не повешу её на кнопку, которая находится в первом html файле. Второй html с контейнером так же как и первый подключён к одному js файлу

Comment: Возможно нужно второй html, который сблоком, подключить к отдельному js файлу, и уже в нём доставать эту инфу из localStorage, но мне ведь нужно повесить эту функцию на кнопку.

Comment: Если первый html выгружается при смене вкладки, а второй стартует, то во втором просто нет этой кнопки скорее всего. Например вышестоящий querySelector(моя_кнопка) выдаёт null, ибо не находит кнопку в html второй вкладки.

Comment: А как тогда можно сделать так, чтобы эта функция срабатывала только при клике на одну кнопку и отобрадала инфу уже во втором html?

Comment: Может быть просто при клике нужно добавлять эту инфу в localStorage, а потом уже во втором html доставать эту ифну?

Comment: Как вы говорили, нужны разные скрипты для этих вкладок или разные условия писать в коде. Показ второй вкладки по сути означает сразу показ информации. Клик там не нужен. Если я верно понимаю вслепую.

Comment: У меня сайт типо кинотеатр, и мне нужно, чтобы "купленные билеты" отображались уже после клика на кнопку "купить"

Comment: Если это происходит в разных браузерных окнах (вкладках браузера (не во вкладках на js)), то у первого документа должна быть кнопка, отправляющая во вторую вкладку, и передающая ей инфу, например через URL или postMessage или сторадж. А вторая вкладка должна заниматься только отображением без лишнего кода. А данные будет получать из URL или слушать message или из стораджа.

Comment: Сработало то, что я предполагал. Я при клике на кнопку не отрисовываю сразу на другой вкладке инфу, а просто добавляю эту инфу в localStorage, а потом уже в отдельном файле второго html беру эту инфу и отрисовываю в блоке

Answer (score 0):

попробуй

```
ticketButton.addEventListener('click', displayTickets);
```

Comment: Неа, не работает

Comment: а если `ticketButton.onclick = function() {displayTickets();};`

Comment: это всё одно и то же

Comment: ну, ему явно не нравится эта строчка...
а как ты объявил кнопку?